# Track user with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

is there a way in google analytics that we can retrieve user information, like ip, time browse etc? I need to track specific user on our website but it seems it was impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics does not display a users IP address to you,  while you could in theory save this in a custom dimension, along with other personal information about your user.

Personal information:

The [Google Analytics terms of service](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html), which all Google Analytics customers must adhere to, prohibits sending personally identifiable information (PII) to Google Analytics (such as names, social security numbers, email addresses, or any similar data), or data that permanently identifies a particular device (such as a mobile phone’s unique device identifier if such an identifier cannot be reset), even in hashed form. Your Google Analytics account could be terminated and your data destroyed if you use any of this information.

Answer: It is not possible to receive personal user specific information from Google Analytics, while it is possible for you to send this information yourself in the form of a custom dimension it is not advisable because it is against the terms of service.

All Information in Google Analytics can not be directly related back to a specific user.